# extract numbers within a string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as below

> "Temporada 2015"

and also I get string as

> "Temporada 8"

I need to match and extract only numbers from the string 2015 and 8.
How do i do it using regex. I tried like below

```
doc.text_at('header.headerInfo > h4 > b').match(/(Tempo).*(\d+)/)[2]
```

But it returned only 5 for first one instead of 2015.
How do I match both and return only nos.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `?` to make the regex non-greedy:

```
doc.text_at('header.headerInfo > h4 > b').match(/(Tempo).*?(\d+)/)[2];
```

Here is a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbTByUlQxQWI4VVU) for verification.

Comment: Wholly my! 4 answers displayed simultaneously! :)

Comment: Yeah, I also had to click that box :)

Comment: @shivam, maybe it had something to do with your avatar.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ROFL..  I think Im too lean to be mistaken as terminator. :D

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` is "greedy". It matches as many characters as it can. So it leaves just one digit for the `\d+`.

If your strings are known to contain no other numbers, you can just do

```
.scan(/\d+/).first
```

otherwise you can just match non-digit

```
.match(/(Tempo)[^\d]*(\d+)/)[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `.*` is greedy which matches all the characters as much as possible, so that it returns you the last digit where all the previous characters are greedily matched. By turning greedy `.*` to non-greedy `.*?`, it will do a shortest possible match which inturn give you  the last number.

```
doc.text_at('header.headerInfo > h4 > b').match(/(Tempo).*?(\d+)/)[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scan directly for digits:

```
"Temporada 2015".scan(/\d+/)
# => ["2015"]
"Temporada 8".scan(/\d+/)
# => ["8"]
```

If you want to include `Temp` in regex:

```
"Temporada 2015".scan(/Temp.*?(\d+)/)
# => [["2015"]]
```

Non regex way:

```
"Temporada 2015".split.detect{|e| e.to_i.to_s == e }
# => "2015"
"Temporada 8".split.detect{|e| e.to_i.to_s == e }
# => "8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it thus:

```
r = /
    \b    # match a word-break (possibly beginning of string)
    Tempo # match these characters
    \D+   # match one or more characters other than digits
    \K    # forget everything matched so far
    \d+   # match one or more digits
   /x

"Temporada 2015"[r] #=> 2015
"Temporada 8"[r]    #=> 8
"Temporary followed by something else 21 then more"[r]
  #=> 21
```

If 'Tempo' must be at the beginning of the string, write `r = /Tempo....` or `r = /\s*Tempo...` if it can be preceded by whitespace. I've written `\D+` rather than `\D*` on the assumption that there should be at least one space.

I don't understand why `'Tempo'` is in a capture group. Have I missed something?